# Не работает сервер node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Запускаю сервер, ошибок нету, но захожу на localhost, а он не открывается.
Код:

```
    require('dotenv').config()
const express=require('express')
const config=require('config')
const pg=require('pg')
const sequelize=require('./db')
const app=express()
const models=require('./models/models')
const errorHandler=require('./middleware/ErrorHandlingMiddleware')
const fileUpload=require('express-fileupload')
const cors=require("cors")
const path=require("path")
PORT= process.env.PORT || config.get('PORT')
app.use(cors)
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'static')))
app.use(fileUpload({}))
app.use('/api',require('./routes/index'))
app.use(errorHandler)


async function start(){
    try{
        await sequelize.authenticate()
        await sequelize.sync()
        app.listen(PORT,() =>console.log(`Server was started on ${PORT}`))
    }

    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}

start()
```

Comment: Что такое app, sequelize? Как запускаете сервер? Как стучите на него?

Comment: Это библиотека для работы с бд,const express=require('express'),const app=express()

Comment: (sequalize) для работы с бд

Comment: @m1dn1ght так на `localhost/`  или все-таки на `localhost:5500/` (какой-то порт)?

Comment: localhost:5000/

Comment: А что Вы ожидали увидеть, открывая `http://localhost:5000/`?

Comment: ничего, просто пустую страницу

Comment: @m1dn1ght здесь ничего не понятно. Либо это не весь пример кода, либо тут не хватает `const express = require('express');  const app = express();`

Comment: Чтобы что-то увидеть, надо чтобы сервер знал, что ему это что-то надо вернуть (и да, пустая страница - это тоже "что-то"). В Вашем коде ничего такого нет. Добавьте хотя бы такую строчку: `app.get('/', (req, res) => res.end());`

Comment: @m1dn1ght я это спросил к тому, что не хватает кода у вас в вопросе.

Comment: Отредачил вопрос,добавил весь код,проблема в том,что бесконечно загружается localhost:5000

Comment: @m1dn1ght раз зависает значит где-то застряла обработка по маршруту домашнего каталога `:5000/`. И вот здесь не так разве надо `app.use(cors())`?

Comment: Мда,как то даже не по себе стало,2 дня искал в чем ошибка,оказалось забыл скобки поставить,спасибо вам)